# Probability: Shouldn't the only two possible outcomes add up to a probability of 1?

Tags: probability

I am learning the basics of probability as a part of the "Concepts of Intelligent Technologies" module at my university.

While reading our study book, Artificial Intelligence (Negnevitsky, 2011), I have come across something that baffled me: after some calculations of odds and probability (given the evidence), the author had concluded that the probably of a dry day tomorrow was 0.8, and the probability of a rainy day tomorrow was 0.71. Regardless of whether the calculations are correct, shouldn't these two probabilities add up to 1? (100%)

As requested, I have added the relevant images. The first two (pages 70-71) have the calculations, and the last one has the formulas used (page 68).

[image]

Comment: Unless you link the book and page number, how would we know?

Comment: If they're mutually exclusive, the sum of the probabilities cannot be more than $1$.  And if they're exhaustive (i.e. no third alternative can happen) then it cannot be less than $1$. But I don't think anyone here will understand what the author of that book did without seeing that passage of the book. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: As noted, it's impossible to say for sure without the context, but those aren't the only possible outcomes. Tomorrow there can be rain (or not), yes. But there can also be a tornado, snow, thunderstorm, meteor shower, ...

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. I was just asking a general question, but if it helps, I will get the specific example from the book. @Inoryy the book was only talking about these two possible outcomes, but even if there were more as you suggested, the issue still stands: why is there more than 100%? Shouldn't all the possible mutually exclusive outcomes add up to 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't add up to 1 because they're not part of same distribution.

"Tomorrow is dry" is actually "Tomorrow is dry, given that today it rains **and** rainfall is low".
"Tomorrow it rains" is actually "Tomorrow it rains, given that today it rains".

Comment: Aitäh sulle (thank you) @Inorry (my wife is Estonian as well :)). Now I understand where the author got the 0.71 from, but I still don't understand why when observing the opposite of the hypothesis (tomorrow is rain) he is using only part of the evidence (today is rain) rather that the whole evidence (today i rain and rainfall is low). Am I missing something?